# Update files for OSX disabled updates

Tags: macos, updates, osx-el-capitan

I've recently downloaded a security update that apparently was not downloaded before. I have installed the package and disabled it;

Where are the files stored after you download and disable an update on OSX server El Capitan v10.11.6?

---

By disabling it I simply mean this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "disabled it"?

Comment: Which files are you referring to being stored?

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm assuming that after you've downloaded something from the App Store and have not enabled the update on the server, then it stores the package somewhere for you to enable it later?

Comment: I was able to find an answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246541/where-does-app-store-download-files-to?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) thank you for your help

Comment: @JunkyGenius Welcome to Super User! I know it's been a month, but it's still good to "close the loop" by adding an answer, even if it's based on information from another SE site :) I have done so, but feel free to add your own too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updates are stored in one of two directories

Per the QA OP linked in comments, **Completed OS installers** are stored in the *Applications folder*.

> OS installers are all called "Install OS X [OS Name]" which might not be what you expected, if you're looking alphabetically for instance for El Capitan.

<sup>Credit to [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246544).</sup>

**Incomplete downloads** are stored under `/private/var/folders` and have an extension ending `.pkg`.

> To find it out for yourself, open "Activity Monitor" -> Select the process "storedownloadd" -> Open files and Ports -> then you should see the path.

<sup>Credit to [JedatKinports](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287569).</sup>